Angular & Spring Boot : 415 Unsupported Media Type Error when Sending FormData with Image and JSON Object
Having used other sources extensively, I am asking for advice here now.
I would like to send data from the frontend (Angular - Typscript) to my backend (Java Springboot).
The data includes two string values, an Array of Objects and an image file. The data should be stored in the data base, only the image file should be stored in a local folder and for each image an image_url is generated in the backend and stored in the database.
For sending data from the service in the frontend to the controller I'm using formData, which should contain all data. For testing purposes, however, I am currently only sending the two string values and image file (not the array of objects) within the given code structure.
However, I keep getting a 415 Wrong Content-Type error, stating that it can't handle application/octet-stream although using formData shold automatically deliver it in the necessary multipart/form-data.
Perhaps someone can identify the cause for this. Strangely, each image is still successfully stored in the assigned local folder.
First, I pass on the data (recipeObj and formData) from the component
private createRezeptObj(recipe: Recipe): any {
  
    const rezeptObj = {
      name: rezept.name,
      onlineAdresse: rezept.onlineAdress,
      image: this.newRecipe.image ? this.newRecipe.image : null
    };

    console.log('createRezeptObj', rezeptObj);
    return rezeptObj;
  }


   saveRecipe(rezept: Rezept): Observable<HttpResponse<RecipeResponse>> {
  

    const recipeObj= this.createRecipeObj(this.newRecipe);
    console.log('recipeObj:', recipeObj);
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    if (this.newRecipe.image instanceof File) {
      formData.append('image', this.newRecipe.image);
    } else {
      console.warn('image not valid:', this.newRecipe.image);
    }


      return this.rezepteService.createRezept(rezeptObj, formData).pipe(
        tap(response => {

          this.newRecipeCreated.emit(this.newRecipe);
          this.updateTagCount();
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          console.error('Error when saving:', error);
          return throwError(() => new Error('Error when saving'));
        })
      );
    }



  handleClick(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    
    const rezeptToSave = this.newRecipe;

    this.saveRecipe(rezeptToSave).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log('Recipe saved:', response);
        this.router.navigate(['/listencontainer']); 
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error in handleClick:', error);

      }
    );
  }

and the RecipeResponse
export interface RecipeResponse {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  onlineAdresse: string;
  tags?: Tag[];
  bildUrl?: string;
}

The service uses the recipeObj for some UI operations and only passes on the received formdata to the backend-url:
createRezept(recipe: Recipet, formData: FormData): Observable<HttpResponse<RecipeResponse>> {
    

this.loadingSubject.next(true);

const imageFile = formData.get('image') as File;
rezept.image = imageFile ? imageFile : null;

console.log('In createRezept: FormData vor dem Senden in BE:', {
 name: formData.get('name'),
  onlineAdresse: formData.get('onlineAdress')
  tags: formData.getAll('tags'),
  image: imageFile ? imageFile : 'No image in recipe-service.ts/create',
});

formData.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log('struktur formData vor ins BE', key, value);
});

const file = formData.get('image') as File;
console.log('File-Typ:', typeof file, file instanceof File);



return this.http.post<RecipeResponse>(`${this.backendUrl}/api/rezepte/create`, formData, {
  observe: 'response'
}).pipe(
  tap(response => {
    console.log('Server Response:', response);
    if (response.body) {
      console.log('Response Body:', response.body);
      const rezeptId = response.body.id;
      }

Now here in the backend, no code inside the createRecipe endpoint is executed because it doesn't even get to that point for the 415 error. I'm using a DTO to receive the recipe here.
@PostMapping(value = "/create", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<RezeptDTO> createRezept(
        @RequestPart(value = "recipe", required = false) RecipeDTO recipeDTO,
        @RequestPart(value = "image", required = false) MultipartFile image
) throws IOException {

The RecipeDTO:
package com.rezepte_app.dto;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Builder
public class RezeptDTO {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String onlineAdresse;
    // Getter und Setter für tags
    @Getter
    private Set<TagDTO> tags;  
    private String bildUrl;

    // Standard-Konstruktor
    public RezeptDTO() {
    }


public RezeptDTO(int id, String name, String onlineAdresse,  String
bildUrl) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.onlineAdress = onlineAdress;

    this.bildUrl = bildUrl; 
}



public String getBildUrl() {
    return bildUrl;
}

public void setBildUrl(String bildUrl) {
    this.bildUrl = bildUrl;
}

}
appplication.properties:
server.servlet.session.timeout=30m
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

